# How read values from certain cells in a spreadsheet beyond VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel-formula

I have report with ID and values in columns. Values are determined 'TRUE' in column. Do you know how make report with two column with ID and value, for e.g.

At the top is the original report and at the bottom of the expected effect.
[image]

How macro to write. This is a simple example, in the future I'll have a more rows with ID and handiwork will be impossible...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Will column A always have exactly the same values in the original and the final report, or could there be some missing values?

Comment: You should try the HLOOKUP function from excel. With a little luck you won't need a macro at all

Comment: Yes column will always the same values, but one ID may not have a counterpart in the column 1,2,3... then will null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your simple example, use the formula `=MATCH(TRUE,B2:F2)` in `B12`

In this [more generic example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIfAS.jpg)

```
Key 101 102 103 104 105
A1                  TRUE
A2      TRUE            
A3      TRUE            
A4              TRUE    
A5          TRUE        
A6  TRUE                
A7                  TRUE
A8                  TRUE

Key Val             
A1  105             
A3  102             
A8  105             
A5  103             
A6  101             
A7  105
```

, I used

```
=INDEX($1:$1,1,MATCH(TRUE,OFFSET($1:$1,MATCH(A12,A$2!:A$9),0)))
```

Comment: Why INDEX function return always first row when [numer_column] argument is error... What with example when A6 haven't value TRUE? Me return value from A1... sick :(

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula in cell B13, then drag it down to the rest :)

```
=MATCH(TRUE,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(MATCH(A13,$A$1:$A$8,0),":",CONCATENATE(MATCH(A13,$A$1:$A$8,0))),TRUE),0)-1
```